# Rewriting an Apache RewriteRule?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

In my application's `.htaccess` file I have the following:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php
```

A very lightweight file that puts all unmatched requests through `index.php`.

However, this application is a social networking website that I've been tasked with making multi-lingual. Therefore, URLs like `www.example.com/profile/martin` need to be converted in to say, Spanish, and will therefore become `www.example.com/perfil/martin`.

Therefore, my question is: is it possible to rewrite a `RewriteRule`? In this instance, I want to rewrite `/perfil/martin` to `/profile/martin`, but then have `/profile/martin` passed to `index.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following line before the 'RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php' line should achieve what you want.

`RewriteRule perfil/(.*) profile/$1`

I'd argue that you should be doing this in your web app's URL routing code though, rather than the htaccess file.

Comment: Really? I started doing that, but thought having dictionaries of these in my application's code would start to become messy and hard to maintain. But then again, no more so than maintaining `.htaccess` rules. Thanks!